# for each loop with undefined number of inside loops

Tags: python-2.7, iteration

Assume `foo` is a list or some other iterator. I want some thing so that I can (pseudo-code):

```
for i in foo
    for j in foo - [i]
        for k in foo - [i, j]
            ...
                for some_var in foo - [i, j, k, ...]//only one value left in foo
                    do_something(some_args)
```

Is there some way to do this in python? Can I do this in a loop, would I have to use recursion, or would I have to make (only if no other way) a code object?

Comment: What does `for j in foo - i` mean? `foo` is apparently an enumeration, so I don't know what `foo - i` is.

Comment: Well, we know `foo` is iterable and assuming a list-like behavior, `i` is an item from `foo` - we just can't guess know what `foo - i` means.

Comment: sorry I'll make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question has to do with combinatorics. Specifically Cartesian products.

Without recursion you need to know how many nestings of loops you are going to run. However you don't need to know this information ahead of time. As long as you can get it dynamically it is ok.

Consider this code taken from one of my repos: https://github.com/Erotemic/utool/blob/next/utool/util_dict.py

```
from itertools import product 
import six

varied_dict = {
'logdist_weight': [0.0, 1.0],
'pipeline_root': ['vsmany'], 
'sv_on': [True, False, None]
}

def all_dict_combinations(varied_dict):
       tups_list = [[(key, val) for val in val_list]
             for (key, val_list) in six.iteritems(varied_dict)]
       dict_list = [dict(tups) for tups in product(*tups_list)]
       return dict_list

dict_list = all_dict_combinations(varied_dict)
```

running this code will result in dict_list being

```
    [
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': True, 'logdist_weight': 0.0},
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': True, 'logdist_weight': 1.0},
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': False, 'logdist_weight': 0.0},
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': False, 'logdist_weight': 1.0},
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': None, 'logdist_weight': 0.0},
        {'pipeline_root': 'vsmany', 'sv_on': None, 'logdist_weight': 1.0},
    ]
```

and then you could write code like

```
  for some_vars in dict_list:
      do_something(some_vars)
```

To relate it back to your example if you were to list each let of values foo can take in each nested level in what I call varied_dict then you can get a solution to your question. Also note that varied_dict can be built dynamically, and it doesn't really have to be a dict. If you modified my code you could easilly specify the values using a list of some other structure.

The magic in the above code comes down to the use of the itertools.product function. I suggest you take a look at that. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product